# SharePoint Search Service is locking files on the fileshare being crawled

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, enterprise-search

SharePoint is locking files on the file share that it's crawling.  At times, we need to be able to delete or replace files with newer versions on this file share, but we're unable to.

Is there any way to prevent SharePoint from locking these files so that they may be deleted?

Comment: There is a read-lock when the crawler index the items - but it should be released very shortly afterwards. Is the lock permanent?

Comment: Yes...sometimes these documents need deleted, but they're somehow becoming corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Process Monitor to see what process locks the file - normally SharePoint releases the file once it's copied for processing.